# MTPro2 and amsbook conflict

Tags: fonts, packages, incompatibility, amsbook

I am using the MTPro2 fonts with `amsbook` class. However something strange happens when I activate the `mtpfrak` option for the alternate fraktur fonts. LaTeX simply ignores it! That is I see the old AMS fraktur fonts. If I change the document class to `memoir`, `report` or `book` the problem goes away! Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: Hi! Just a quick observation: I can replicate your problem for the `amsart` documentclass as well. :-(

Comment: if this doesn't work with `amsbook`, it won't work with any other ams document class (`amsart`, `amsproc` and all author package classes). i can't remember than anyone has ever asked for these classes to be checked for compatibility with the MTPro2 fonts.  i will look into it.

Comment: i have tested an example document with `amsart` and `\usepackage[mtpfrak]{mtpro2}`.  "ordinary" `\mathfrak` is produced with no complaint, and the output looks good.  but if i try to use the *alternate* forms (`\altx` et al.), there is a complaint `Package mtpro2 Warning: Invalid use of \altx on input line ...`.  on the other hand, the alternate *script* letters work just fine.  i am puzzled, but will continue to investigate.

Comment: Thank you, my wording is bad in above. You see, mtpro2 has another complete set of fraktur alphabet which you can use if you load the mtpfrak option. My complaint is that this font does not appear, even after enabling the option. One only gets the computer modern fraktur fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen the same issue but can circumvent it by using

```
\usepackage[frak=mt]{mathalfa}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[mtpfrak]{mtpro2}
```

whence the trivial example

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage[mtpfrak]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[frak=mt]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKL abcdefghijklm} \]
\end{document}
```

produces a pdf that evince reports as having CMR7 and MT2MFT fonts, as intended.

A similar example using `amsbook` has the following in the output log:

```
</home/mas/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></ho
me/mas/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mft.pfb>
Output written on mtproamsfrak.pdf (1 page, 20064 bytes).
```

Moving the '%' down to the next line in both examples results in the AMS frak font being used:

```
</home/mas/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></ho
me/mas/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eufm10.pfb>
Output written on mtproamsfrak.pdf (1 page, 22155 bytes).
```

Comment: This is a great solution to a disturbing problem!

Comment: Thank you this works but given the fact what they charge for mtpro2 I did not expect such problems ...